# PHP: Implications of a abrupt termination of a request by a *fatal* error

Tags: php, fatal-error

I'm experiencing a strange situation.

My application logs lot of trace logs to a file. (I don't know exactly how, I use my frameworks logger. Can check this though)

Problems is, when an application is terminated by a **fatal** error (only fatal) [example - "Fatal error: Call to a member function someFunction() on a non-object"] , I end up with no logs, even logs that should have been recorded much earlier during the execution of my script.

(Yes, I tried to flush logs, this doesn't help either. It looks like the termination of the application by a fatal error, somehow cancels writing to files done at earlier points of the application.

Any ideas what goes on here?

Thank  you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the fatality of the fatal error that Pascal mentioned, is not 100% fatal.

The below allowed me to have my logs even on fatal errors:

```
function correctShutdown()
{
   logger->flush();
}

register_shutdown_function('correctShutdown');
```

Answer (score 3):

A Fatal Error is... well... **Fatal** : it stops the execution of the script, which will not do anything that should have been done.

In your case, I suppose your logging framework logs into memory -- and that this in-memory log is only written to the file when the processing of the request is done.

Some logging mecanisms do that, to avoid writing to a file several times, at different points during the generation of the response *(which means keeping the file locked, to avoid concurrency problems ; or opening-closing-reopening-reclosing-... it)*

As you get a Fatal Error, the normal operation that should be done at the end of the response's generation is not called -- and, so, the in-memory log is not written to the file.

Now, the only way to know for sure would be to take a look at the logging mecanisms of your Framework ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation about the logging mechanism. That's exactly what Yii does, and this is the root cause for the situation.